# How to get inside an arrow method call of a mocked object using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, powermockito

I have this below method that I need to test using Mockito. In this method, there is a mocked Class object "refDataCache" which calls a method and inside it, there is an arrow function. How to write test, so that I can enter inside the `refDataCache.forAllMetaBlock` method and check for `metaBlockEntity.getMetaBlockId()` and `metaBlockEntity.getCode()`.

```
// Test code class snippet
public class MetaInfoControllerTest {
    MetaInfoController metaInfoController;
    @Mock
    RefDataCache refDataCache;
    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        metaInfoController = new MetaInfoController(refDataCache);
    }
}

// Actual Method //
@GetMapping("/metaBlocks")
    public Map<String, String> getMetaBlock() {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        refDataCache.forAllMetaBlock(metaBlockEntity ->
                response.put(Long.toString(metaBlockEntity.getMetaBlockId()), metaBlockEntity.getCode())
        );
        return response;
    }
```

My test code is never able to enter inside the `refDataCache.forAllMetaBlock` and it directly jumps to `return response` on debugging.

Comment: How are you mocking the `refDataCache`? Include details about that in the question. like whether it is a spy or a mock, etc.

Comment: This is precisely how mockito works - you have an unstubed method (called only for its side effect), so mockito ignores the call. It is not clear what refDataCache is, and whether mocking it is a right thing to do.

Comment: @GauthamM added the mock code of refDataCache

Comment: @Lesiak refDataCache is required to be mocked and in the case of this method, refDataCache is just calling a method with arrow function, In all previous cases refDataCache was calling either void methods or methpds with just one or two params.

Comment: Additionally, RefDataCache is a decompiled class.

Comment: If anyone has ever come across such cases of arrow funcntions inside a method of a mocked class, do share your idea of how to do it for full line coverage in the method.

Comment: 1. You say "refDataCache is required to be mocked". Why? You haven't told us anything about the class other than "it is decompiled" - probably meaning you don't own the source code. 2. Guessing by the name, it caches some data. Even if you use real object instead of a mock, the cache may by empty in your test. We have no way to know without seeing the code. 3. You seem to be testing only for code coverage. Don't. This is an anti-pattern. Test for some interesting properties in the code.

Comment: @Lesiak Yes , I have been only given task for writing tests on this code, and on seeing the name of refDataCache, its a class for caching data only i guess.